# String templates in Python: what are legal characters?

Tags: python, string, templates

I can't quite figure out what's going on with [string templates](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.Template):

```
t = Template('cannot teach an ${dog.old} ${tricks.new}. ${why} is this ${not} working')
print t.safe_substitute({'dog.old': 'old dog', 'tricks.new': 'new tricks', 'why': 'OH WHY', 'not': '@#%@#% NOT'})
```

This prints:

```
cannot teach an ${dog.old} ${tricks.new}. OH WHY is this @#%@#% NOT working
```

I thought that the braces handled arbitrary strings. What characters are allowed in braces and is there any way I can subclass `Template` to do what I want?

Comment: +1: Linked the documentation. -1: Didn't actually read the linked documentation.

Comment: WTF? I did read it, I'm fairly new to Python and to its documentation style (vs. javadoc where things are fairly verbose). Thanks for jumping on me for missing one small detail.

Comment: All of programming is small details.  The fact that you linked to the documentation at all is a cut above many questions on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation...

> $identifier  names a substitution placeholder matching a mapping key of "identifier". By default, "identifier"  must spell a Python identifier. **The first non-identifier character after the $ character terminates this placeholder specification.**

The period is a non-identifier character, and braces are simply used to separate the identifier from adjacent non-identifier text.

Answer (score 5):

Aha, I tried this experiment:

```
from string import Template
import uuid

class MyTemplate(Template):
    idpattern = r'[a-z][_a-z0-9]*(\.[a-z][_a-z0-9]*)*'

t1 = Template('cannot teach an ${dog.old} ${tricks.new}. ${why} is this ${not} working')
t2 = MyTemplate('cannot teach an ${dog.old} ${tricks.new}. ${why} is this ${not} working')
map1 = {'dog.old': 'old dog', 
    'tricks.new': 'new tricks', 'why': 'OH WHY', 'not': '@#%@#% NOT'}
map2 = {'dog': {'old': 'old dog'}, 
        'tricks': {'new': 'new tricks'}, 'why': 'OH WHY', 'not': '@#%@#% NOT'}  
print t1.safe_substitute(map1)
print t1.safe_substitute(map2)
print t2.safe_substitute(map1)
print t2.safe_substitute(map2)
```

which prints

```
cannot teach an ${dog.old} ${tricks.new}. OH WHY is this @#%@#% NOT working
cannot teach an ${dog.old} ${tricks.new}. OH WHY is this @#%@#% NOT working
cannot teach an old dog new tricks. OH WHY is this @#%@#% NOT working
cannot teach an ${dog.old} ${tricks.new}. OH WHY is this @#%@#% NOT working
```

so the third one (`print t2.safe_substitute(map1)`) works.

Comment: Gaaahhhh.. periods in property values are so common across languages. Why is this so awful!

Answer (score 1):

<s>Python interprets the `.` in your name as "access the field `old` of the instance `dog`". Try `_` instead or make `dog` an object with a field `old`.</s>

AFAIR, only valid identifiers and `.` are safe between the braces.

[EDIT] It's on the page where you link to:

> `${identifier}`  is equivalent to `$identifier`. It is required when valid identifier characters follow the placeholder but are not part of the placeholder, such as `"${noun}ification"`.

and

> `"identifier"` must spell a Python identifier.

which means: It must be a valid identifier.

[EDIT2] It seems that the identifier isn't analyzed as I thought. So you must specify a simple valid Python identifier in the braces (and you can't use the field accessor syntax) unless you create your own implementation of the [Template class](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.Template).

Comment: ok, thanks! Where is this documented, and is there any way to override it?

Comment: To override, you can derive subclasses of Template  to customize the placeholder syntax.

Comment: This is not correct, and is not mentioned in the documentation.  Otherwise, `print t.safe_substitute({'dog': {'old':'old dog'}, 'tricks': {'new':'new tricks'}, 'why': 'OH WHY', 'not': '@#%@#% NOT'})` would work, and it does not.

Comment: To paraphrase Aaron: "It's on the page you linked to". That is, *you* linked to http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.Template . Just scroll up a couple lines.

Comment: @MikeWyatt: You may be right but not for the reason you mention. The syntax `dog.old` doesn't work on a dictionary. It must be `dog['old']`. I'm talking about *instances* but I agree that the documentation doesn't say it works.

Comment: To whoever downvoted Aaron: he fixed his mistake, please consider rescinding downvote; this was a helpful answer.

Comment: @Aaron: Maybe I'm missing something, but dog['old'] also doesn't work.  Have you tried that syntax in IDLE?  Without looking at the Template source code, it seems like the default implementation only supports basic identifiers.

Comment: @MikeWyatt: I've edited my answer. Apparently, only basic identifiers work.

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks.  I removed the down vote.  If you don't mind me being a little pedantic, you might want to strike out the incorrect content at the top of your answer, or reword it to mention subclassing Template.